# How to deploy nativescript-barcodescanner in typescript?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, barcode-scanner

I am trying to run demo from https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-barcodescanner/tree/master/demo both locally and online at https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=CB7XFu&v=2 but no luck. On the playground I have added the plugin.

I noticed there is a similar question here [How to use BarcodeScanner plugin from NativeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40393983/how-to-use-barcodescanner-plugin-from-nativescript) but seems it's 3 years before and the plugin changed a lot after that.

Can anyone try the playground and tell which line I got wrong? I strictly followed the demo in github. The error message is `Can't find variable: QRCodeReaderDelegate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Playground (online) Or Preview command (locally), You can not use plugin those require native dependency such as Barcode Scanner.

You will have to build the project using `tns [run|build]` commands locally, only then the native dependencies will be installed and you will be able to run them successfully.